# How to connect Raspberry to Grove Components?

Tags: hardware, gpio, peripherals

Has anybody already connected some [Grove Components](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GROVE_System) to the Raspberry Pi?

How do I connect the system? And where can I find code tor program it?

Answer (score 2):

Grove is a system of some nicely packaged sensors designed to be used with SeeedStudio's [Grove shields](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Base_Shield) for Arduino. Since many of them are analogue sensors, you'd need an external ADC for the Raspberry Pi. Alternatively, you could [attach an Arduino](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-to-attach-an-arduino) and communicate through that.

Comment: I've got the feeling that all Grove components use the i2c bus and hence bring their own ADC - am I wrong?

Comment: They don't look like i2c; they have separate analogue and digital plug components.

Comment: Take 3-Axis Analog Accelerometer as an example. It is using 3 pins that are directly connected to Arduinos analog pins.

Comment: ok - I see: there are some I2C components (eample http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_I2C_3-axis_Accelerometer) , but most of them are analog or digital...

Comment: There are 4 types of grove sensors - Analog, Digital, UART and I2C. There is a complete list on the [Seeed Studio wiki](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove)

Comment: Check the pins on each sensor socket. Analog/Digital = SIG,NC,VCC,GND. UART = TX,RX,VCC,GND. I2C = SCL,SDA,VCC,GND. The NC stands for Not Connected (those sensors only use 3 of the 4 pins on the socket)

Answer (score 2):

Might be an old post but incase anyone finds this without knowing - the grovePi came about to solve this I think:
http://www.dexterindustries.com/GrovePi/

Answer (score 1):

This github repo also shows how to connect a single Grove sensor directly to a Raspberry Pi, however their examples will only work with a limited set of their sensors (I assume only digital sensors).

https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove-RaspberryPi

Answer (score 1):

What really makes it easy to connect Grove Connectors to the Raspberry Pi, is to add a Grove shield to the Raspberry Pi, like the Pi2Grover connector.

Then it becomes plug and play with all your Python drivers available.

Here is a tutorial on how to use the devices: [Tutorial: Intro to Grove Connectors for Arduino/Raspberry Pi Projects](http://www.switchdoc.com/2016/02/tutorial-intro-to-grove-connectors-for-arduinoraspberry-pi-projects/).