# Is there an Arduino software package for programming, USB?

Tags: arduino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to attach an Arduino?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-to-attach-an-arduino)

I'm about to get an Arduino, and I would like to hook it up to my Raspberry Pi to program it. I know that Arduino works on Linux, but I also know that having the right software can help considerably. Are there libraries available to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the Arduino IDE on the Raspberry Pi, but it's a bit slow. It's in the Raspbian repositories: `sudo apt-get install arduino`.

The Arduino can just appear as a simple serial device, and you can use any protocol you want. I've used [pyFirmata](https://bitbucket.org/tino/pyfirmata/src) successfully. There's also a question here which asks much the same: [How to attach an Arduino?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-to-attach-an-arduino/1507)