# is it possible to connect a raspberry pi to an arduino via USB and have them communicate?

Tags: usb, arduino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to attach an Arduino?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-to-attach-an-arduino)

I have ready through this website:

http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-spi/

which indicates you can get a pi to communicate with an arduino using SPI, but is it possible to do the same with USB?

Is there a tutorial that explains how this can be achieved?

And if it is possible, does this mean the arduino would be powered by the raspberry pi?

Comment: Check out this other question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-to-attach-an-arduino.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason you couldn't. All you would need to do is learn how to communication over serial connections in linux. If you're drawing a lot of power you should use powered usb hub.